# What is the significance of the wolf in last episode of the first season of "Fargo"?

Tags: analysis, fargo-tv

In the last episode of the first season of Fargo,
Gus is driving a car when he suddenly spots a wolf in the middle of the road.
This makes him stop the Car and also coincidentally identify Malvo's location.

Later, when Malvo is wounded and sitting on his sofa, the wolf appears again, in front of his window. Just about then, Gus appears and shoots down Malvo.

Is there anything particular that the creators wanted to convey through this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wolf is a predator. I'm sure you remember the riddle Malvo asked Gus:

> Do you know why the human eye can see more shades of green than any other color?

Malvo considered himself a predator. He valued only predators and liked changing people into them (like he did with Lester).
And for the meaning of the scene here is a quote from [an interview](http://www.tvguide.com/news/fargo-finale-noah-hawley-1083116/) with one of the showrunners Noah Hawley:

> "Obviously it's the whole predator-prey thing where Malvo goes back to the cabin and he's almost mortally wounded," showrunner Noah Hawley tells TVGuide.com. "And he looks out the window and sees that wolf ... and that's the moment that Gus comes out, and that smile on his face, Malvo is realizing that he's not the predator anymore. There is a lot of animal symbolism in the show -- from fish to deer to wolves -- and that's not an accident."